# Getting Files From Program Files

Tags: java, file

hey so on my game today I added my cache into my installer so the user does not have to have it in there c: drive so I changed my code to this

```
public static String findcachedir() {

    return System.getProperty("C:/Program Files/TheIronDoor/667cache");
}
```

But when I go to use the code nothing shows the images and ect doesn't show like it is not there so I asked my friend and he said it may be the spaces I had between The Iron Door so I removed the spaces but it is  still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return System.getProperty("C:/Program Files/TheIronDoor/667cache");
```

This will return a JVM property by this name... Ie, it will certainly return `null`!

You probably wanted to return `"C:/Program Files/TheIronDoor/667cache"` instead.

Comment: Dont get what you are getting at